# Theorem 11 of Section 2.5 in Hoffman, Kunze

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

**Theorem 11.** Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers and let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field.
Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$ and $\dim(W)\leq m$. Then there is precisely one
$m\times n$ row-reduced echelon matrix over $\mathbb{F}$ which has $W$ as its row space.

I saw the proof, and the existence of such a matrix is already proved...

I summarize what I understand in the proof of uniqueness of such a RREM, and kindly help whether the proof in the book also demonstrates the same thing or is there some other idea involved in that proof..

Let R be such a RREM of W, let the first $r$ rows of R are only non-zero, and let R has the leading non-zero entry of Row $i$ in Column $k_i$
the idea is to prove that any vector in W cannot have its leading entry (Given in Coordinate form) in $j$th place, where $j<k_1$. and there exists one atleast one vector in W such that $k_i$th co-ordinate of that vector is non-zero, (i.e the row vectors of R)

If we proved this then Let R' be any other RREM having W as its row space then the leading non-zero entry of the $i$th row is in $k_i$th column.

Let $p_i$ and $q_i$ be the $i$th row of R and R' respectively, then by properties of RREM and the discussions above,

$p_i$ and $q_i$ will have it's $k_i$th entry as $1$ and $k_j$ th entry's are zero for $j \ne i$ and they both agree for entries $s>k_r$, (suppose $\exists s>k_r$, such that the $s$th entry of $p_i$ is not same as $q_i$ the $p_i-q_i$ will have all the entries zero upto $k_r$ th entry and $s$th entry is non-zero, which means this vector $p_i-q_i \in W$, but no linear combination of the vectors in R will give $p_i-q_i$,

So we proved that if R and R' are two RREM which has same row space as W, then both of them will have only r non-zero rows and the $i$th row vectors in both of them have leading entry in $k_i$th place and by the above argument both of them are equal..

Is this idea correct and is it the same idea used in the original proof in the book,
IF NOT, kindly tell what's wrong and give a summary of the idea of the proof in the book. TIA